# Raising an Event in .net - perfomance implications

Tags: .net, performance, memory

Throwing an exception is costly in terms of writing good performance code. But what about raising an event?  Hence this theoretical querstion to the .net clr  crowd: 

What are the memory implications concerning raising an event with one subscriber? With 1 000 000 subscribers? How to calculate these implications? Does raising one event euqal calling a member method of (the otherwise handler) subscriber directly?

Comment: This is trivial to measure yourself.  Use Stopwatch.

Comment: @Hans, great answer - but I'll leave it to you to keep mastering that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Raising an event" usually just means "calling a delegate" - but potentially a multicast delegate with many invocations in its list. Each of these is pretty cheap... not much more than a direct method call usually, although there are situations which are more expensive. (IIRC, call a delegate which has been created via an interface method is more expensive.)

I strongly recommend that you write the most natural code to start with, and then test it to see if it performs well enough. I can't immediately think of a *quicker* way to effectively call a bunch of subscriber methods. I *suspect* it's generally as cheap as iterating over a list of interface implementations and calling an interface method on each, and it may well be significantly cheaper in some situations.

Comment: I was just typing my answer starting with “I'm sure Jon Skeet will come up with a more definitive answer”—well, I was asking for that.

Comment: great, thank you as always for the insight. It is great to have you here!

Answer (score 1):

The main implication is that you can not control the implications if you make the event public. Any subscriber can take an hour to process your event, block indefinitely or might even throw you an exception. Usually this lack of control is not a big problem, since either you have control over all subscribers yourself or you are creating a component to be used by others and then the users of your component are responsible for the usage and the event handlers they subscribe.

Raising an event would be about the same performance as calling the same number of methods as the subscription count.